# How can I limit the information (metadata) that is being sent to Google from an Android Phone?

Tags: android, google

I am thinking about rooting my phone and removing some bloatware apps (like google+ and so on) that come with it. Are there any other ways to limit Google's information about that specific phone?

Comment: When you root your device, even that information will be sent to google by **safety net**.

Comment: I think that I can use RootCloak to hide my root from SafetyNet.

Comment: What information you don't want google to see?

Answer (score 2):

Doing the following would help in controlling the data being sent out.

1. Root your phone
2. Install a firewall (Eg: **Comodo Antivirus**, **Avast Mobile Security**)
3. Turn on firewall for applications which you don't want to communicate with the server.
4. Uninstall bloatware and unnecessary google apps using **System app remover [ROOT]** [ Make sure that the services you uninstall are absolutely unnecessary for the operation of the phone]

Answer (score 0):

Some options allow you to opt out of sending various data sources to google. I'd suggest however limit linking your accounts or switch data off entirely

Comment: Is it possible that Google won't respect that?